# Changing varchar column to foreign key of another table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to change a column's varchar values to it's id foreign key value from another table, and I can't seem to make the conversion, always throws an error.

User table...

```
CREATE TABLE User(
UserId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName VARCHAR(50),
LastName VARCHAR(50),
Email VARCHAR(50),
Username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
RoleName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LastLogin DATETIME,

PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
);

INSERT INTO User 
 (FirstName, LastName, Email, Username, Password, RoleName)
VALUES
```

...

RoleName table...

```
create table rolename(
                RoleId int not null auto_increment,
                RoleName varchar(50),
                primary key(RoleId)
);
insert into rolename(RoleName) select distinct RoleName from user;
```

Now, what I need to do is have the RoleName column in the User table point to the key in the RoleName table. I keep trying this, but always gives me an error.

```
update user set user.`RoleName` = rolename.`RoleId` from user inner join rolename on user.`RoleName` = rolename.`RoleName`;
```

I'm not sure if I'm setting up the foreign key properly with that code either...

Comment: It was mock data for an inclass excercise, I did not write the database, just the lookup table but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are doing this wrong.  You put the `id` in the `User` table.  To fix this:

```
alter table user add roleid int;
alter table user add constraint fk_user_roleid foreign key (roleid)  references rolename(roleid);
```

Then populate the values:

```
update user u join
       rolename r
       on r.rolename = u.rolename
    set u.roleid = r.roleid;
```

And get rid of the old column!

```
alter table user drop column rolename;
```

Comment: alter table user add constraint fk_user_RoleId foreign key (RoleId); I'm still getting an error from that line

Comment: Meant to upvote this answer before, sorry. I did get it working, Thank you @Gordon Linoff